# Word-wrap in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

Here in content-full class I have used word-wrap: break-word; still the text do not appear in proper format?What could be the possible solution to it?Is there some way to get a  proper format so as to  Allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line.But wierd part is that for content-short word-wrap:break-word is working!

```
echo "<div class='mainlayout' data-js-module='layout'>";
echo "<div class='grid' style='position: relative;'>";
include "mysql.php";
$query= "SELECT ID,Title,Summary,Content,ImgName,Image FROM content ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query,$db);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
    echo "<div class='grid-item item1' style='position: relative; left: 240px; top: 0px; background: ".ran_col().";'>";           
    echo "<div class='content-short' style='position:relative;'>";
    $string = $row['Content'];
    if (strlen($string) > 200) {
        $trimstring = substr($string, 0,200). '...';
        } 
        else {
            $trimstring = substr($string,0). '...';
            }
    echo $trimstring;
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='content-full'>";
    echo $row['Content'];
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
mysql_close($db); 
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";  
?>
```

and the styling for content-full

```
<style type="text/css>
    .content-full{
        border: 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        float: left;
        background: white;}
    .content-short {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
        padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        height: auto;
        width: 200px;
        background: White;}
</style>
```

Comment: If your class name is "content-full" why do you style it as "content-full-data"?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.i just changed that to .content-full it was  a typing mistake @Arturo

Comment: Have you tried adding "display: inline-block"?

Comment: yes i have still the same problem@Arturo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i encountered the same problem you i am using a text from docx file and while uploading i used pre tags so then word-wrap do not work properly. if this is your case remove pre tags.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :**

if it is external , it will be like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pathto.css">
```

the parent div bypass this div style , try to change the style of parent div like the following :

change this line :

```
 echo "<div class='grid-item item1' style='position: relative; left: 240px; top: 0px; background: ".ran_col().";'>";
```

by this :

```
 echo "<div class='grid-item item1' style='position: relative; word-wrap: break-word; left: 240px; top: 0px; background: ".ran_col().";'>";
```

it will inherit your mentioned div

Comment: i have used external style sheet @Mohammed Elhag                                                                                                                    <style type="text/css>
.content-full{
    border: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    float: left;
    background: white;
}
</style> this was just used to show my styling for respective class

Comment: ive used same syntax to llink to external stylsheet @Mohammed Elhag

Comment: thanks but i have written  correct class @Mohammed Elhag

Comment: I am sure the above div , <div class='grid-item item1' bypass this div style , try to get add word-wrap: break-word; to <div class='grid-item item1' parent div

Comment: did that still no effect@Mohammed Elhag

Comment: maybe you need to chack this  , background: ".ran_col().";' , change it to direct name , for example background:red , then check

Comment: no still the same effect.ran
_col() is a function i have defined myself whose code i have not put here@Mohammed Elhag

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to accomplish?
https://jsfiddle.net/9s2zr7gL/
If so, just add this to your current CSS:

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
 word-break: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
```

You also need to add "lang=en" as a parameter in your div. Otherwise it won't work in firefox.
If your text is not in English, check if the language is supported:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens

Comment: i want to achieve same thing as in jsfiddle link you gave,but it didnt work for me @Arturo

Comment: @aryan_kanwar Check all your CSS properties affecting that div, if it works in the jsfiddle it has to work for you. In which language is your text written?

Comment: in english language @Arturo

Comment: @aryan_kanwar Have you added the lang="en" parameter to your div?

Comment: @aryan_kanwar Could you create a jsfiddle with your non-working content attempt and link it here?